# Getting a SUM of the values in INNER JOIN adds up duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am running a query which is counting the records on monthly basis from the table. 
I am trying to add one extra column called "TotalPrice", I need a sum of all the prices from 'settle' table.

The problem I am facing is because of INNER JOIN, 'SUM' of the prices is adding up multiple prices due to duplicate records which the INNER JOIN is returning. Is there a way to avoid it and get a SUM of the prices from unique records ?

```
SELECT
CONCAT(year(datetime), '-', month(datetime)) AS YearMonth,
COUNT (DISTINCT a.id) AS TOTAL, SUM(total_price) AS TotalPrice
FROM settle AS a with (nolock)
     INNER JOIN transfers b with (nolock) ON b.settleId = a.id 
     INNER JOIN Fdata AS c with (nolock) ON c.id=  b.data 
GROUP BY CONCAT(year(datetime), '-', month(datetime))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume each `id` has one `total_price` per `datetime`?

Comment: yes its one.. I want the SUM of all the total_price for a month... I can't use SUM( DISTINCT  total_price) because there could be same price for more than one records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sql server 2008 onwards:

```
with CTE as -- A CTE alows us to manipulate the data before we use it, like a derived table
(
select datetime, id, total_price, 
       row_number() over(partition by id, datetime order by total_price) as rn -- This creates a row number for each combo of id and datetime that appears
FROM settle AS a with (nolock)
     INNER JOIN transfers b with (nolock) ON b.settleId = a.id 
     INNER JOIN Fdata AS c with (nolock) ON c.id=  b.data 
)
SELECT CONCAT(year(datetime), '-', month(datetime)) AS YearMonth,
       COUNT (DISTINCT a.id) AS TOTAL, 
       SUM(total_price) AS TotalPrice
from CTE
where rn = 1 -- that row_number we created? This selects only the first one, removing duplicates
group by CONCAT(year(datetime), '-', month(datetime))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked,, can you also please explain it to me ?