# How to execute subquery once based on the group by

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dataverse

I have a large query in a Dynamics 365 SQL Server database where I have an issue.

I try to reproduce the issue in a small query here:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE invoices 
(
    PersonID int,
    InvoiceId int,
);

INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName) 
VALUES (1, 'test', 'test')

INSERT INTO invoices (PersonID, InvoiceId) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO invoices (PersonID, InvoiceId) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO invoices (PersonID, InvoiceId) VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT INTO invoices (PersonID, InvoiceId) VALUES (1, 4)
INSERT INTO invoices (PersonID, InvoiceId) VALUES (1, 5)

SELECT
    p.PersonID,
    SUM(s1.number)
FROM
    Persons p
-- INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.PersonID = p.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 5 AS number) AS s1 ON number > 1
GROUP BY 
    p.PersonID


SELECT
    p.PersonID ,
    SUM(s1.number)
FROM
    Persons p
INNER JOIN
    invoices i ON i.PersonID = p.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 5 AS number) AS s1 ON number > 1
GROUP BY 
    p.PersonID
```

Running the query I get this result:

[image]

So if I make also a inner join to invoices it's will going to make the
sub query to `left outer join (select 5 as number) as s1` times the amount of invoices, and later by grouping by PersonId and making a sum
on `s1.number` it's will be `sum(s1.number)` * the amount of invoices,
if someone can help me how to avoid this, and if I make a inner join and sub query and make a group by, it's should only take the result from the sub query once based on the group by

I cannot use any temporary table solution because it's restricted in Dynamics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a SUM of the values in INNER JOIN adds up duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168566/getting-a-sum-of-the-values-in-inner-join-adds-up-duplicate-values)

Comment: dynamics restrict the with statement, so I cannot use the this solution

Comment: You can use a subquery or a correlated subquery?

Comment: What is the purpose of the ``LEFT OUTER JOIN   (SELECT 5 AS number) AS s1 ON number > 1``? What is desirable result?

Comment: this is just a dummy Sql to reproduce my problem in my long query(where I make a large calculation in the sub query)

Comment: Perhaps you can do [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/3bTI8RwR)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the invoices based calculation in a subquery which groups by PersonID, then join that subquery:

```
SELECT
    p.PersonID ,
    SUM(s1.number)
FROM     Persons p
INNER JOIN     invoices i ON i.PersonID = p.PersonID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 5 AS number) AS s1
GROUP BY 
    p.PersonID
```

| PersonID | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |

```
SELECT
    p.PersonID ,
    s1.number
FROM     Persons p
INNER JOIN  (
      /* do the calculations here */
      select PersonID
      from invoices 
      group by PersonID
      ) AS i ON i.PersonID = p.PersonID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 5 AS number) AS s1
```

| PersonID | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCfDejhc)

Your cut-down query does not actually indicate where the calculation(s) are happening. The point is that it is natural for SQL to MULTIPLY rows when joining tables. To counteract this (correct and expected) behaviour, when aggregating, you may have to do some calculations in a subquery and join that result instead of the raw table.